# Values of for loops are not printing in proper order

Tags: java

My following code is not printing the values in proper order.

```
 int q = 1,lt=0,va=0,tv=0;
 for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfLOB.size();j++) { 
     System.out.print(totalNoOfLOB.get(j).getText());

for(int p=q+1;p<combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.size();p++)
    {
    System.out.print("          " + combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.get(p+1).getText());
             break;
      }

 for(int tl=lt+0; tl<thresdhholdsLowerValues.size(); tl++)

    {  
  System.out.println("          "+ thresdhholdsLowerValues.get(tl).getText());
                break;
      }
 for(int av=va+1; av<listOfActualValues.size(); av++)

   { 
    System.out.println("                                                     "+ listOfActualValues.get(av).getText());
                break;
    }

  for(int tt=tv+0; tt<listOfActualValues.size(); tt++)

   { 
    System.out.println("                                                                          "+ listOfToTarget.get(tt).getText());
                break;
     }
  q++; lt++; va++; tv++;


             }
```

This is output, its not printing output proper order.  The  last 2 columns values are going little down.

```
Output:::::
Manager         66%          65%
                                        19755/29871
                                                          4142
Manager AAA       80%          0%
                                        17/21
                                                           0
Manager BBB       75%          74%
                                        2515/3350
                                                           165
Emply         57%         56%
                                        1808/3125
                                                           692
```

It should print in following manner:

```
Manager      66%      65%   19755/29871     4142
```

All values should be print in one line for all 5 rows.

Comment: `System.out.print` vs `System.out.println`.

Comment: Why are you using for-loops if you immediately exit them after the first iteration?

Comment: when used for 4th loop still going down and the values of 5th loop got not displayed. Using number of for loops because all loops having different size.

Comment: Used System.out.printf for all loops and System.out.println at last has resolved that issue but how do i print the first character of each column in same line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get the Reference of [this link](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/spacing-output-java-32722.html).

Go to format setting, where you  find the following code
the first argument is the number of character space you want, and the second is the output you want to print.

```java
System.out.format("%4d", i); System.out.format("%3d", j); 
System.out.format("%3d", k); System.out.println();
```